# How does Microsoft Edge categorize items in Task Manager on Windows 11?

Tags: winapi, microsoft-edge, taskmanager, windows-11

[Microsoft Edge does an interesting job of categorizing and customizing nested items in Task Manager on Windows 11](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/10/12/improving-edge-processes-task-manager/), such as GPU Process, Crashpad, Browser, Extensions and much more:

[image: A picture of Microsoft Edge in Task Manager with nested items such as GPU Process or Crashpad]

What API are they using to do this?

Comment: Is that Windows 11's Task Manager? I'm using Windows 10 and I don't see that view (in the Processes tab, right?)

Comment: @Dai yes, it is. I'll add that to the question. Good catch

Comment: I did some digging - it looks like Edge is using some undocumented or otherwise internal API to provide extra process and window metadata to Task Manager. I did see some people elsewhere on the Internet speculate that Edge was using Task Manager's existing window-list-subtree functionality (and making child icons unique by creating stub `hWnds` with custom icons and titles for the tree children) but this does not appear to be the case because Task Manager does not show 3+ tree node levels when it's listing windows. Time to bust out Ghidra, methinks.

Comment: I agree with Dai's comment. Microsoft doesn't make the APIs public. If you want to know more about the APIs, I think you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge to see if they can provide more information.